# Periodic app restarts in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

We're running a Node.js/Express application which runs for a few hours and will then start to throw 504 errors for no good reason. Since we're currently unable to track these errors down we need to restart the application every hour or so to ensure it's still running during the weekend.

Our Ubuntu server runs [Dokku](http://github.com/progrium/dokku), which then has a container setup for our application. Every time the application spits a 504 we have to run `docker restart appid` as root.

So what's the best way of automatically restarting the node process every hour?

Comment: Have you tried using "forever" (npm install forever), you can run it via its CLI with "forever start <your app>.js". It should relaunch your node.js app if it exits unexpectedly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> throw 504 errors for no good reason

It's throwing these because you application is crashing

> currently unable to track these errors down

You have to track them down. They are very likely unhandled exceptions which you can catch and log via:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
   //look Ma, I died
});
```

> So what's the best way of automatically restarting the node process every hour?

Since I'd feel bad not at least attempting to address you actual question, even though you are most certainly fixing the symptom instead of the problem in a seriously bad way...

Use cron. Put a script in `/etc/cron.hourly/restart_express` to do it. Make sure the script file has execute permissions and conforms to the `run-parts` naming constraints (no dots, etc).

Comment: It's not that I don't want to fix it, I do! I'm sick of restarting the application every few hours, but I've spent hours trawling through our — actually pretty tiny — codebase looking for a fix. Nothing gets spat out in the errors, it just dies.

Comment: Perhaps the Linux Out Of Memory Killer is killing it? If you have a pretty tiny app that is exiting and you don't know why, this is seriously bad. Get help figuring it out or rewrite it or something, but that's a dire situation. Hire someone to code review it or help you debug or whatever.

Comment: I've got a feeling it's something to do with the MySQL connections. Although we pool them together, I feel as if it's killing the connections somewhere. Thanks for the cron stuff, this'll do for now.

Comment: Instead of using cron you could also look into using monit

Comment: If the app crashes you could use monit, Supervisor, god, or any other process manager to restart it automatically. Well, even something like "while true ; do node app.js ; done" might do the trick :-)